# Creating object instances globally

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-office

this is probably something I should know, but I'm puzzled by this.
I'm trying to create some objects and being able to access and modify these globally.

I tried to create a Public Module and declare a few objects in this.
I am able to access these from another sub, but I get an exception error when after building and runing the process and trying to modify these object.

The same thing happens if I declare the object in the Public Class Form1. For example like this:

```
Public Class Form1
Public appWord = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Public wordDoc as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
```

Now, in my button, I've got this:

```
wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open("c:\temp\test.dot")
appWord.Quit()
appword = Nothing
```

After I've built the project and press the button, I get this error:

```
Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005(DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
```

What I'm trying to do is to start a Winword.exe and then load a template in that and read some macros from the template. Then I want to be able to replace the macrocode from my application and then store the changes to the macro. And I've got a Public sub which reads the macro and puts the text in a textbox. And then I've got a separate Public Sub which does the replacement. However, I'm trying to figure out a clever way of creating these objects one time so I don't have to do it over and over again.

Edit: This doesn't happen if I declare the object in the same sub as the button, like this:

```
Private sub Button1_Click
Dim appWord = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim wordDoc as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

wordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open("C:\temp\test.dot")
appWord.Quit()
End sub
```

Edit: I got it working now. There wasn't an error, it was just that the document didn't exist.. I'm an idiot :)

Comment: When do you get this error? What code is being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're getting has nothing to do with the way you declare your "globals". It's a Dispatch interface error telling you the type you're passing is not what the interop class is expecting, that is, the call to Open is probably wrong. According to [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open%28office.11%29.aspx) it should be passed by reference (so a literal string is not valid).

Comment: But why is it working when I declare these objects in the same sub as the one I modify it in? See my edited first post for details.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot.. The document doesn't exist..
Thanx for clearing this up! There you see how a human typo can ruin everything! :)

Comment: We keep learning only till we think "I'm an Idiot". When we think we are genious - the progress stops!!